# Missing words in word2vec vocabulary

Tags: word2vec

I am training word2vec on my own text-corpus using mikolov's implementation from [here](https://github.com/tmikolov/word2vec/blob/master/word2vec.c). Not all unique words from the corpus get a vector even though I have set the min-count to 1. Are there any parameters I may have missed, that might be the reason not all unique words get a vector? What else might be the reason?

To test word2vecs behavior I have written the following script providing a text file with 20058 sentences and 278896 words (all words and punctuation are space separated and there is one sentence per line).

```
import subprocess


def get_w2v_vocab(path_embs):
    vocab = set()
    with open(path_embs, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
        next(f)
        for line in f:
            word = line.split(' ')[0]
            vocab.add(word)
    return vocab - {'</s>'}


def train(path_corpus, path_embs):
    subprocess.call(["./word2vec", "-threads", "6", "-train", path_corpus,
                     "-output", path_embs, "-min-count", "1"])


def get_unique_words_in_corpus(path_corpus):
    vocab = []
    with open(path_corpus, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
        for line in f:
            vocab.extend(line.strip('\n').split(' '))
    return set(vocab)

def check_equality(expected, actual):
    if not expected == actual:
        diff = len(expected - actual)
        raise Exception('Not equal! Vocab expected: {}, Vocab actual: {}, Diff: {}'.format(len(expected), len(actual), diff))
    print('Expected vocab and actual vocab are equal.')



def main():
    path_corpus = 'test_corpus2.txt'
    path_embs = 'embeddings.vec'
    vocab_expected = get_unique_words_in_corpus(path_corpus)
    train(path_corpus, path_embs)
    vocab_actual = get_w2v_vocab(path_embs)
    check_equality(vocab_expected, vocab_actual)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This script gives me the following output:

```
Starting training using file test_corpus2.txt
Vocab size: 33651
Words in train file: 298954
Alpha: 0.000048  Progress: 99.97%  Words/thread/sec: 388.16k  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_w2v_behaviour.py", line 44, in <module>
    main()
  File "test_w2v_behaviour.py", line 40, in main
    check_equality(vocab_expected, vocab_actual)
  File "test_w2v_behaviour.py", line 29, in check_equality
    raise Exception('Not equal! Vocab expected: {}, Vocab actual: {}, Diff: {}'.format(len(expected), len(actual), diff))
Exception: Not equal! Vocab expected: 42116, Vocab actual: 33650, Diff: 17316
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're using Python, you might want to use the `Word2Vec` implementation in the `gensim` package. It does everything the original Mikolov/Google`word2vec.c` does, and more, and is usually performance-competitive.

In particular, it won't have any issues with UTF-8 encoding – while I'm not sure the Mikolov/Google `word2vec.c` handles UTF-8 correctly. And, that may be a source of your discrepancy.

If you need to get to the bottom of your discrepancy, I would suggest:

- have your `get_unique_words_in_corpus()` also tally/report the total number of non-unique words its tokenization creates. If that's not the same as the `298954` reported by `word2vec.c`, then the two processes are clearly not working from the same baseline understanding of what 'words' are in the source file.
- find some words, or at least one representative word, that your token-count expects to be in the final model, and isn't. Review those for any common characteristic – including in context in the file. That will probably reveal why the two tallies differ.

Again, I suspect something UTF-8 related, or perhaps related to other implementation-limits in `word2vec.c` (such as a maximum word-lenght) that are not mirrored in your Python-based word tallies.

Comment: Thanks, my text file is utf8-encoded, so it probably is a encoding related error. I will try out the gensim implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [FastText](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText) instead of Word2Vec. FastText is able to embed out-of-vocabulary words by looking at subword information (character ngrams). Gensim also has a FastText implementation, which is very easy to use:

```
from gensim.models import FastText as ft

model = ft(sentences=training_data,)

word = 'blablabla' # can be out of vocabulary
embedded_word = model[word] # fetches the word embedding
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54709303/3275464